# Error while installing GeoPandas libraries using prompt

Tags: python, geopandas, pandas

I am getting this error when trying to install  GeoPandas libraries.....
Anyone with a solution?

```
(base) C:\Windows\system32>conda install -c conda-forge geopandas
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: |
```

Comment: Leave your base env alone and create a fresh env usually works better `conda create -n newenv -c conda-forge  geopandas and any other packages` then `conda activate newenv`